# Invoke a generic method with a subtype of the generic parameter type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to invoke a generic method via reflection using a subtype of the generic parameter type. Here's the situation :

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> where T : class
{
}

public static class Caller
{
    public static void Do<T>(MyClass<T> param1, string param2 = null) where T : class
    {

    }
}

public class ConcreteClass : MyClass<string>
{

}
```

However when I try to do :

```
ConcreteClass instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcreteClass));
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Caller).GetMethod("Do");
methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ConcreteClass));
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { instance, Type.Missing });
```

I am getting an exception essentially saying :

> Cannot convert type 'ConcreteClass' to type 'MyClass`[ConcreteClass]'

The exception message is very clear, however I don't seem to find how I can achieve what I am after.

Edit:

The compile time equivalent for what I am trying to achieve is :

```
Caller.Do(new ConcreteClass());
```

Which compiles fine.

Comment: Not sure if it's just from the example, but does `MyClass<string>` conform to your `MyClass<T> where T : class` requirements?

Comment: @Dan-Cook Many thanks for your interest in the question, yes it generally does (the string constraint is just for the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConcreteClass` extends `MyClass<string>` so you need to provide `typeof(string)` to `MakeGenericMethod`:

```
ConcreteClass instance = (ConcreteClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ConcreteClass));
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Caller).GetMethod("Do");
methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { instance, Type.Missing });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reflection-based code is attempting to the runtime equivalent of `Caller.Do<ConcreteClass>(instance, Type.Missing)`.

This is invalid. The method `Do<>` requires matching types - for `Do<ConcreteClass>`, you need an instance that is or is a subclass of `MyClass<ConcreteClass>`.

`ConcreteClass` is a subclass of `MyClass<string>`. For this, you would need to call `Do<string>(instance)`, or overall, `Caller.Do<string>(instance, Type.Missing)`.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance but something is incorrect I'm afraid. Doing Caller.Do(new ConcreteClass()) is perfectly accepted by the compiler, therefore there should be a way to have the same approach using reflection.

Comment: That's because the compiler can correctly infer the correct types. With your reflection code, however, you're explicitly supplying an invalid combination of types.